# Calling a command and retaining formatting and data type

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a Linux command from here https://github.com/scragg0x/FFXIV-Scraper:

```
lodestoner topics
```

That returns data like this:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.4.1-py2.7.egg/bs4/__init__.py:166: UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

To get rid of this warning, change this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup])

to this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup], "lxml")

[
    {
        "body": "<div class=\"area_inner_cont\">\n<a href=\"//na.finalfantasyxiv.com/lodestone/topics/detail/2f33323151437bd543ae8637766e0bd3c6d741ac\"><img alt=\"\" height=\"149\" src=\"http://img.finalfantasyxiv.com/t/2f33323151437bd543ae8637766e0bd3c6d741ac.png?1452844930\" width=\"570\"/></a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\tThe date has been set for the twenty-seventh installment of the Letter from the Producer LIVE! Streaming live from <b class=\"text-strong\">Kagoshima</b>, Japan, Producer &amp; Director Yoshi-P will answer questions from players across the globe. Don't miss this chance to get the latest information to come out of Eorzea!<br/>\n<br/>\r\nRead on for <a href=\"//na.finalfantasyxiv.com/lodestone/topics/detail/2f33323151437bd543ae8637766e0bd3c6d741ac\" rel=\"2f33323151437bd543ae8637766e0bd3c6d741ac\">details</a>.\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>",
        "lang": "en",
        "title": "Letter from the Producer LIVE Part XXVII",
        "timestamp": 1452844800,
        "link": "//na.finalfantasyxiv.com/lodestone/topics/detail/2f33323151437bd543ae8637766e0bd3c6d741ac",
        "id": "2f33323151437bd543ae8637766e0bd3c6d741ac"
    },

.......

    "title": "The \u201dLetter from the Producer LIVE Part XXVI\u201d Digest Released!",
```

I'm looking to script this in Python and retain the formatting. I've done this:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['lodestoner', 'topics'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(xml, err) = proc.communicate()
exit_code = proc.wait()
```

But it does not seem to preserve the formatting:

```
b'[\n    {\n        "body": "<div class=\\"area_inner_cont\\">\\n<a href=\\"//na.finalfantasyxiv.com/lodestone/topics/detail/2f33323151437bd543ae8637766e0bd3c6d741ac\\"><img alt=\\"\\" height=\\"149\\" src=\\"http://img.finalfantasyxiv.com/t/2f33323151437bd543ae8637766e0bd3c6d741ac.png?1452844930\\" width=\\"570\\"/></a>\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\tThe date has been set for the twenty-seventh installment of the Letter from the Producer LIVE! Streaming live from <b class=\\"text-strong\\">Kagoshima</b>, Japan, Producer &amp; Director Yoshi-P will answer questions from players across the globe. Don\'t miss this chance to get the latest information to come out of Eorzea!<br/>\\n<br/>\\r\\nRead on for <a href=\\"//na.finalfantasyxiv.com/lodestone/topics/detail/2f33323151437bd543ae8637766e0bd3c6d741ac\\" rel=\\"2f33323151437bd543ae8637766e0bd3c6d741ac\\">details</a>.\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t</div>", \n        "lang": "en", \n        "title": "Letter from the Producer LIVE Part XXVII", \n        "timestamp": 1452844800, \n        "link": "//na.finalfantasyxiv.com/lodestone/topics/detail/2f33323151437bd543ae8637766e0bd3c6d741ac", \n        "id": "2f33323151437bd543ae8637766e0bd3c6d741ac"\n    }]'
```

Am I missing anything? How can I bring this into Python and handle it properly (BeautifulSoup/XML)? For example, if I wanted to print `title`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a json string (byte-string). Decode it using [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) after decode the byte-string into a string:

```
(xml, err) = ...
...

objects = json.loads(xml.decode())
print([o['title'] for o in objects])
```

---

If you want to just print the xml, decode `xml` (byte-string object) and print:

```
print(xml.decode())
```

Comment: I think that's on the right track, but some symbols seem to be tripping it up. It's printing: `['Letter from the Producer LIVE Part XXVII', 'Changes to the Disk Space Requirements for FINAL FANTASY XIV: A Realm Reborn on All Platforms', 'The â
                                                                                                                                                    Ending script` and nothing more (there are 10+ items). I edited in that line/symbols to my OP.

Comment: Good call, it was just PuTTY not being able to render unicode. Had to make some client settings, displays now.